# Swift / menu (view) causing randomly "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Menu.xib with 5 UIButtons. I'm calling this view within my ViewController on a button IBAction. When I try to run my code the compiler throws randomly:

> Segmentation fault: 11

When I comment my code or randomly parts of it like: `menuView.locationBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.goLocation), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)` the code might work or might not. Randomly. I'm on this error since a while now and can't find the issue.

```
@IBAction func menuBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let menuView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Menu", owner: self, options: nil).last) as! Menu

    menuView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100)

    menuView.homeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.goHome), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menuView.bookmarkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.goBookmark), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menuView.locationBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.goLocation), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menuView.photoBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.goPhoto), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menuView.friendsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.goFriends), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menuView.settingsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.goSettings), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(menuView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        var newMenuFrame = menuView.frame
        newMenuFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - 63
        menuView.frame = newMenuFrame
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (success) -> Void in

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeVC.hideOnTap(_:)))
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}

func goHome() {
    print("home")
}


func goBookmark() {
    print("bookmark")
}

func goLocation() {
    print("location")
}

func goPhoto() {
    print("photo")
}

func goFriends() {
    print("friends")
}

func goSettings() {
    print("settings")
}

func hideOnTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.viewWithTag(5)?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

When I uncomment the whole code everything works fine. I have done something like that often in other projects without any problems... Help is VERY appreciated...

Compiler message:

```
    0  swift                    0x000000010c3ea66b llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 43
    1  swift                    0x000000010c3e9956 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 70
    2  swift                    0x000000010c3eaccf SignalHandler(int) + 287
    3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff932ba52a _sigtramp + 26
    4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000020000 _sigtramp + 1825987312
    5  swift                    0x000000010a5581a8 swift::ModuleFile::getType(llvm::Fixnum<31u, unsigned int>) + 872
    6  swift                    0x000000010a558f53 swift::ModuleFile::getType(llvm::Fixnum<31u, unsigned int>) + 4371
    7  swift                    0x000000010a558e44 swift::ModuleFile::getType(llvm::Fixnum<31u, unsigned int>) + 4100
    8  swift                    0x000000010a554d53 swift::ModuleFile::getDecl(llvm::Fixnum<31u, unsigned int>, llvm::Optional<swift::DeclContext*>) + 16259
    9  swift                    0x000000010a55793f swift::ModuleFile::maybeReadPattern() + 575
    10 swift                    0x000000010a557a92 swift::ModuleFile::maybeReadPattern() + 914
    11 swift                    0x000000010a55382e swift::ModuleFile::getDecl(llvm::Fixnum<31u, unsigned int>, llvm::Optional<swift::DeclContext*>) + 10846
    12 swift                    0x000000010a55baa9 swift::ModuleFile::readMembers(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::Decl*>&) + 249
    13 swift                    0x000000010a55dfbe swift::ModuleFile::loadAllMembers(swift::Decl*, unsigned long long) + 206
    14 swift                    0x000000010a89d43c swift::NominalTypeDecl::getMembers(bool) const + 28
    15 swift                    0x000000010a83e3f7 (anonymous namespace)::Traversal::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*) + 247
    16 swift                    0x000000010a83a266 (anonymous namespace)::Traversal::doIt(swift::Decl*) + 230
    17 swift                    0x000000010a83a16b swift::Decl::walk(swift::ASTWalker&) + 27
    18 swift                    0x000000010a3b13ab swift::ClassHierarchyAnalysis::init() + 155
    19 swift                    0x000000010a3a8ef1 swift::createClassHierarchyAnalysis(swift::SILModule*) + 129
    20 swift                    0x000000010a42108d swift::SILPassManager::SILPassManager(swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef) + 317
    21 swift                    0x000000010a4290c6 swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 118
    22 swift                    0x000000010a13d457 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 12903
    23 swift                    0x000000010a13968d frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2781
    24 swift                    0x000000010a1350ac main + 1932
    25 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff918085ad start + 1
    26 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000007a start + 1853848270
    Stack dump:

bla bla unreadable crap

1.  While loading members for 'HomeVC' at <invalid loc>
2.  While deserializing decl #173 (PATTERN_BINDING_DECL)
3.  While deserializing decl #10 (VAR_DECL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to completely solve it with "pod update". I will leave it, in case someone runs into the same problem.

It brought me to the next problem. My bridging header was not working anymore. I had to clean the project with CMD + ALT + SHIFT + K (very important to clean it **WITH ALT**, the usual clean had no effect!) and run the pod install again. Now everything is working again.